# f:ajax event not fired if parent input is rendered disabled

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Given the simple setup:

```html
<h:inputText disabled="#{true}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" execute="@form" render="@form" event="blur" />
</h:inputText>
```

If the input field is programmatically enabled via a DOM manipulation (say JQuery), the #{bean.listener} method is still never invoked, because no AJAX request to the server is made. I can see the reason why: when it first renders the input field, the renderer apparently thinks it is disabled and will remain disabled forever, so it doesn't even bother to render the necessary Javascript that makes the AJAX call.

Questions:

1. Is there a workaround other than ensuring that the EL expression in disabled always evaluates to true when originally rendered?
2. Why doesn't it just always render the necessary javasript, in which that javascript code itself checks, before submitting the AJAX request, whether or not the element is currently enabled to decide to dispatch the AJAX request.
3. Also, it seems that if an element is originally rendered as disabled, but then programmatically enabled via a DOM manipulation, that it will also not update the model value of the backing bean?

Comment: 1. workaround for what? It's not that clear for me. 2. For security purposes, JSF creates the component view and stores it (yes, JSF is like a stateful HTML) and won't allow changes from a malicious client (like your doing from your web), and this design has its benefits and can gives you *issues* like this case. This also applies for 3.

Comment: I don't see why it matters. I would expect any security considerations to be handled at a different tier of the application, not in JSF, which isn't a security framework like JAAS, etc. Who cares if a malicious client enables an input field and then causes a method to be called on the server? If it's that important for some method not be called or something not to happen, any sane developer would have other security measures in place in different layers to prevent something like this from happening and wouldn't be trusting client submitted data or a 3rd party framework in the first place.

Comment: *Who cares if a malicious client enables an input field and then causes a method to be called on the server?* **JSF cares**. JSF stores the state of the component tree before being rendered, and when submitting the `<h:form>` it will first validate if the component tree still matches with the previous version, if not then it will stop the processing and reuse the first component tree. If you don't want JSF to *care* about this security issue (which is not easily covered in other web MVC frameworks), then you can disable state since JSF 2.2.

Comment: You can read more about this here: [JSF STATELESS VIEWS AND CSRF PROTECTION](https://blog.dominikschadow.de/?p=685)

Comment: Why does it care then? Again, is this REALLY helping the overall application to be more secure, or is it just causing more developer annoyance and headache? Is anyone really just going to call a very security locked method from within a JSF action listener and just assume that since the JSF lifecycle decided it was okay to call the method, then no other authorization or authentication validation mneasures would take place??? I don't think so. And unfortunately, we are stuck on JSF 2.1 for the meantime.

Comment: Well... you're trying to do so. I'm just telling you how JSF works and cares of this (JSF doesn't care if you like this or not :P). Anyway, you can mark the `<h:inputText>` as `disabled` in your `onload` event using JavaScript rather than using `disabled="#{true}"` and don't worry about this anymore OR use a variable from your managed bean (I assume it's at least `@ViewScoped`) which value is `true` and when you perform the (ajax) operation to enable the `<h:inputText>` change the value of this variable to `false` and keep everything in JSF-way.

Comment: And yes, it helps the app to be more secure. Seems that you don't know or you haven't suffered from CSRF in the past.

Comment: Of course I could just always render it as true and on DOM load, disable it or enable it like implied in my first question. I don't want to do it the pure JSF way because for such simple things there is no reason to make a server call for the sole purpose to enable a single input, especially in an environment where every server request is going through multiple corporate proxies along the way. I know what CSRF is, but in our environment and with other security measures in place, it is a non-issue.

Comment: Well, you already know how to solve. If you still don't want to believe, maintain the question open, otherwise, choose an option.